# Control windows application from web page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, signalr

I have a web application (ASP.NET 2010) where user login into the application to perform some tasks. Some of the tasks are related to hardware connected to user PC.

Since it is impossible to connect to client PC attached hardware from web application, I have developed a windows application (VB.NET 2010) to connect to the hardware.

The windows application is connected to the same web application through SignalR.

To map the commands from the web application to the windows application, The same user login into the windows application also to map both through the Username.

Is there any other way to let windows application run automatically on windows startup without user login, and keep the mapping so user commands from the web application pass to the windows application running on the same PC of the user?

Noting that many users are using the same application, so I need each user commands from the web application to pass to the dedicated user PC?

Comment: I guess you could record the IP address of the user when they login via the web app and if you then get a request from the Windows app on the same IP, let it through without requiring login.

Comment: But what about if the PC is behide a router, the IP will not be the PC IP address, is it?